# CocoaPods error : Ignoring ffi-1.14.2 because its extensions are not built

Tags: ruby, cocoapods, ios-simulator, ffi

After Firebase configuration, I try to run the simulator IOS 15.2 on iPhone 8 with visual Studio code with the command "run without debugging" but I get this error :

```
    Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 8 in debug mode... CocoaPods' output:
Error output from CocoaPods: Ignoring ffi-1.14.2 because its extensions are not built.
Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.14.2
        [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
Error running pod install Error launching application on iPhone 8.
Exited (sigterm)
```

and when I run the error suggestion :

```
    ismac@ismails-MacBook-Pro flutter_chat % gem pristine ffi --version 1.14.2
    Ignoring ffi-1.14.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.14.2
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.
```

Can you please help me ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the solution that worked for me.

follow this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EXp0gq9kGxI
then open Podfile in ios folder and change :

> "# platform :ios, '9.0'" to  "platform :ios, 'current_version_of_ios'"

current_version_of_ios : is the real version of IOS in the moment you read this solution then before run the simulator :

Delete the podfile.lock file from iOS folder after that go to ios folder and run a below command

```
Pod install
```

It will install all the packages which are in your podfile.

Also, you need to set the target platform. Stay in the iOS folder and run below command

```
open Runner.xcworkspace
```

then your app will be open in XCode. Click on the "Runner" and set your target platform to 8.0. I fix my iOS build issue using this hope this will work for you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30777099)

Comment: @MarioPetrovic ,it's done.